# How link web frontend to backend

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

How I can automatically pass backend link\ip for frontend ?

I have two services:

```
services:
  core:
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - pws.vlm.logs:/var/www/pws/logs
    networks:
      - pws-net
    environment:
      DB_URL: postgres://pws_pg_user:${DB_PASSWORD:-default_password}@postgres/pws
      NODE_ENV: ${NODE_ENV:-production}
      JWT_SECRET: ${JWT_SECRET}
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - 3100:3080
  web:
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - pws.vlm.logs:/var/www/pws/logs
    networks:
      - pws-net
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: ${NODE_ENV:-production}
      API_URL: ${API_URL:-http://127.0.0.1:3100}
    depends_on:
      - core
    ports:
      - 3000:3080
```

If I want to make api calls from frontend to backend I need to take ip address from host or domain name and pass it to web container as `API_URL`, Is there some opportunity to use docker networks to pass link to backend by container name, so I can set API_URL=core and It automatically substitute on ip or domain ?

Comment: Does the `web` service serve up formatted HTML, or is it something like an Angular or React app where the `API_URL` gets called from an end user's browser?

Comment: yes, web it is frontend react app

Comment: It needs to be an externally visible host name that can reach the published service, something not unlike the `http://...:3100` you show; it cannot be a Docker Compose service name.  I'm not familiar enough with Swarm to know the details here.

Answer (score 2):

Docker compose orchestrates the containers so that they contact each other directly. Just use the used name of the backend as hostname, in this case `core`. You still have to append the port, but the backend is reachable under `http://core:3100`

so the entry for web would look like this:

```
  web:
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - pws.vlm.logs:/var/www/pws/logs
    networks:
      - pws-net
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: ${NODE_ENV:-production}
      API_URL: http://core:3100
    depends_on:
      - core
    ports:
      - 3000:3080
```

Comment: It works even throw browser, when user load app to his machine ?

Comment: That won't work as the browser on the host accesses the docker container. In that case you still have to use `localhost:3001`

Answer (score 1):

Your service names (`core` and `web`) act as the DNS entries. You can use `http://core:3100/api` from frontend to access the services of backend.